# VBA to Insert Values from Multi-Value Lisbox into Separate Table (Run-time error 3075)

Tags: vba, listbox, insert-into

This is my first post and hoping to get some help. I have done plenty of research but can't determine where I'm going wrong. I simply want to loop through a multi-value listbox and add the values to a separate table.

I have code that I think should work but I keep getting Run-Time error 3075 Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '1b'.

Here's my situation:

I have a table: qaTbl

I have two fields in this table. interactionID and defect (this is the multi-value listbox). Both fields are shortText.

For each record submitted, I want to place the interactionID and defect (regardless if one defect is selected or many) into a new table called callDefectsTbl.

The two fields in callDefectsTbl is interactionID and defect.

I have a form with a submit button (qaSubmit). The control for the listbox is 'defect'.

Here is the code tied to the Click() Event of the submit button:

```
Private Sub qaSubmit_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim varItem As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb
' Add each defect selected in the list box to callDefectsTbl
With Me.defect
For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
    strSQL = _
        "INSERT INTO callDefectsTbl " & _
            "(interactionID, defect) VALUES (" & _
            Me.interactionID & ", " & .ItemData(varItem) & ")"
    db.Execute strSQL
Next varItem
End With


DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

I get a Run-time error 3075. It seems to be stopping when grabbing the value of defect. I have studied other code that is doing the same thing but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any help and thorough explanation would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If shorttext change sql with single quote

strSQL = _
        "INSERT INTO callDefectsTbl " & _
            "(interactionID, defect) VALUES ('" & _
            Me.interactionID & "', '" & .ItemData(varItem) & "')"

Comment: Thank you! This solves the syntax error; I appreciate it. However, now the values are not populating in the callDefectsTbl. I entered some dummy records in the form and the code ran with no issues but didn't update the table. There were two instances where it did work, but I'm not sure what happened. Maybe I have some properties on the listbox wrong?

Comment: Just simply add msgbox strSQL then see if sql is correct.  I think Me.interactionID may be blank. You can use Docmd.runsql instead of db.execute